# Xamarin Component says "Already Installed" and its really not

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Came across this error today and thought be useful a self Q / A.

Your components list **does not** contain a given Xamarin component, but when you got to add it you get this type of screen -

[image]

So, if this happens, how do I clean up the components from my system so I can install them correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is nearly in this post -

https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1865772-where-are-the-components-stored-on-my-machine

But as well as cleaning out your

- Local project Components folder in root
- ~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/Components on Mac

You also need to clear out

- ~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/ComponentInfo

I did not seem to need a clean up on my Windows Machine even though I was using Visual Studio, but clean the windows folders from the link above if you need to.